# How to retrieve stdout when piping several commands in Go

Tags: docker, go, ssh, pipe, instance

I'm writing a Go function to upload local Docker images to an instance that has SSH access. I'm using the following method for this:

```
        cmdSave := exec.Command("docker", "save", image)
        cmdLoad := exec.Command("ssh", fmt.Sprintf("%s@%s", user, externalIP), "docker load")

        read, write := io.Pipe()
        cmdSave.Stdout = write
        cmdLoad.Stdin = read

        var buffer bytes.Buffer
        cmdLoad.Stdout = &buffer
        var stderrSave bytes.Buffer
        cmdSave.Stderr = &stderrSave
        var stderrLoad bytes.Buffer
        cmdLoad.Stderr = &stderrLoad

        err = cmdSave.Start()
        if err != nil {
            return errors.Wrap(err, stderrSave.String())
        }

        err = cmdLoad.Start()
        if err != nil {
            return errors.Wrap(err, stderrLoad.String())
        }
        err = cmdSave.Wait()
        if err != nil {
            return errors.Wrap(err, stderrSave.String())
        }

        err = write.Close()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        err = cmdLoad.Wait()
        if err != nil {
            return errors.Wrap(err, stderrLoad.String())
        }

        _, err = io.Copy(os.Stdout, &buffer)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
```

However because of the way the commands are piped, if there is a problem with e.g. the SSH key or `WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!` error presents itself when SSHing to the instance, the functions just hangs endlessly on the cmdSave.Wait() and no output is displayed, leaving the user unaware of what the problem is.

Is there a way to do this so that the output isn't swallowed and the function isn't left hanging?

Comment: The "output isn't swallowed" part can be done via not simple piping but by splicing in a io.TeeReader and a goroutine reading and displaying the T-'ed stream. This at least lets you become aware of the problem.